# Automatic count of compiles in Eclipse/Android development toolkit

Tags: android, eclipse

Im looking for an automated way to update a counter for each time I compile a project. Im going to deploy several test versions of an app and need to keep track of what the testers are referring to.

Im also lazy soo it would be great to find a way of automatically add a build numbering system either by time stamp or by an incremented int.

I could do that in Emacs but for this project Im using Eclipse. Is there a good way of doing it there? I basically want to update a line in the strings.xml with a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all your personal day to day builds using the Eclipse GUI, then use Ant (operating on the same source files but producing output in a defined directory) for the alpha/beta releases. Android tools provides a build.xml which you can modify to include a [build number task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html)